# Is the statement update `table` set `field` = `field` + 1 atomic in InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, atomic

Is the statement `` update `table` set `field` = `field` + 1 where `id` = 1; `` atomic in InnoDB?
Or it's be executed as `` select new_field from `table` where `id` = 1; update table set `field` = new field where `id` = 1; ``

Answer (score 1):

Yes, single `UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements are atomic and no other pending transactions can modify the row while the operation is in progress.

InnoDB will perform a consistent, non-locking, and repeatable read of the same row throughout the duration of the transaction regardless of what any other transaction has done to that row. With InnoDB you can also use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` or `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE`, to perform a locking read at the start of your transaction to prevent modifications to that row by other transactions if you need additional processing before committing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an update statement incrementing a field is atomic.